# Automatic registering delphi function to Lua

Tags: function, oop, delphi, lua, registering

im extending delphi app for Lua scripting. And i am wondering if is there any way to automatically register all my object functions?
I know when i want to register some function it has to be luaCFunction.
i got something like this:

```
function RegisterMyPersonFunction(l : PLua_State) : Integer; cdecl;
var
  person : TLuaPerson;    
  Age: Integer;
begin

  if (lua_gettop(l) < 1) then 
    exit;

  person := TLuaPerson(LuaToTLuaObject(l, 1)); 
  Age:=luaL_checkinteger(l,2);
  person.SetAge(Age);
  result := 0;

end;
```

What i want is that i dont want to write for every my function own function like this. Is there any way how to register all these functions from delphi object to lua?
Im using this [wrapper](https://github.com/felipedaragon/pLua-XE)

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Write a tool to generate the reg code from a text file that lists the functions to be registered

Comment: Im not sure if i get what you mean ...could you be more specificor could you give me some simple example?

Comment: @larkone - In other words, you need to write a program which will write programs for you.